# Saltar secuencia de lineas en C

Tags: c

quisiera saber en ocaciones como

```
printf("Indicanos tu nombre: ");
    gets(nombre);
    printf("Indicanos tu apellido: ");
    gets(apellido);
    printf("Indicanos tu dni: ");
    scanf("%d",&dni);
```

donde hay un printf seguido de un scanf, se puedan ver los printf sin necesidad de que el usuario vaya ingresando su "nombre" y seguido salga el otro printf

Nombre
Apellido
DNI

En ves de que tenga que primero poner un dato para que salga el segundo

¿Eso es posible en C?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Lo puedes intentar así: `scanf("%s %s %d", nombre, apellido, &dni);` Con este código, si el usuario ingresa: `David Román 1223` cada dato por separado se almacenará en dichas variables, sin embargo, con la función *scanf* solo podrás leer cadenas sin espacios.

Comment: `gets` es una función peligrosa. Fue eliminado de C en 2011. Necesitas un compilador actualizado.

Comment: Usa [`fgets`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) en lugar de [`gets`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets). Intenta [`fflush(stdout);`](https://es.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) después de `printf`.